# react-query (tanstack-query) reuse an item from cache of items

Tags: react-query

Imagine a typical use-case when you have a list of items and an item view.

So there is an endpoint to get all items. But also you can fetch a single item with `/items/:id`.

But you can avoid fetching a single item if it's already fetched from the `/items` endpoint. So how would you handle that with `react-query`?

```js
function Items() {
  cosnt itemsQuery = useQuery('items', fetchItems);
  // render items
}
      
function SingleItem({ id }) {
  // you can have another query here and refetch item from server
  // but how to reuse an item from query cache and fetch only if there is no such item?
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found answer in the docs

UPD3 https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/initial-query-data

```js
const result = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['todo', todoId],
  queryFn: () => fetch(`/todos/${todoId}`),
  initialData: () => {
    // Use a todo from the 'todos' query as the initial data for this todo query
    return queryClient.getQueryData(['todos'])?.find((d) => d.id === todoId)
  },
})
```

Comment: What if it is not loaded yet? How do you trigger it to fetch?

Comment: @chrisjlee you can use `ensureQueryData` instead of `getQueryData`. This will fetch the data if it does not exist yet.